# is made of bamboo or was made of bamboo in a sentence

Tags: tense

The organ in Las Pinas Church is made entirely of bamboo.
The organ in Las Pinas Church was made entirely of bamboo.
Whic is more suitable,is made or was made?

Answer (score 4):

If the organ still exists and you are talking about the present time, you should use the present tense. If the organ no longer exists, you should use the past tense. You should also use the past tense if you are referring to an earlier time, even though the organ still exists (which it does). So:

The organ in Las Pinas Church **is** made entirely out of bamboo. (It isn't, but never mind.)

The organ in Las Pinas Church, which **was** destroyed by fire in 2015, **was** made entirely out of bamboo. (Fortunately, this never happened.)

The organ in Las Pinas Church **was** made entirely out of bamboo because bamboo **was** cheap and plentiful at the time. (Here, we are referring to the time when it was made even though it still exists.)

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein - Maybe I should have put "Unfortunately, this never happened."?

Comment: No, it's perfect as is.